# How to represent a 'play count' relationship in Entity Framework - Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Say I have a simple audio player app with two entities, `User` and `Tracks`. There are a fixed number of tracks, users can choose to listen to them. I want to keep track of each user's play count for each track. What's the easiest way to represent this in Entity Framework? I have some ideas, but none of them seem particularly elegant.

- Each user could have a property with a dictionary where the keys are track IDs and the values are ints. But they'd all have to be modified if a track was added. And I'd have to like... serialize to json to store in the DB, which is gross.
- There could be a `Listen` entity that gets added to a `Listens` table every time a track is played, and the track totals for each user could be reconstructed from it. This is how a lot of star rating systems work. But this seems wasteful to me, when all I really want to keep track of is a couple dozen ints for each user. And reconstructing the data I want feels like unnecessary
- A many to many relationship doesn't seem like it would quite fit the issue. Each track would have many users (that have listened), but not a count of how many times. And each user would have many tracks (that they've heard), but again now count.

Is there some cleaner way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option you outlined would be my preference.  It correctly models the relationship you're describing at the database level and should be more understandable in code as well.

If you really dislike the idea of adding a record for every time a track is listened to you could just add the record on the first listen per user and have it contain a counter that gets incremented on consecutive listens.  However, I think this is worse as it will be difficult to extend later; say for example if you wanted to keep track of listen dates as well.  You would also have to take extra care if incrementing the counter in concurrent situations.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. It just seems a little excessive, but I guess it's not exactly expensive in terms of resources.